# How to copy files from local machine to remote virtual machine?

Tags: remote-desktop, virtual-machine, windows-xp

Is there an easy way I can copy files directly from my machine to the virtual machine? 
I have downloaded a lot of .HTML files on my desktop and I need them on the virtual machine, I noticed that I cannot just copy and paste there. If that doesn't work (copy/paste) I am sure there is a way to share the files I cannot remember.

**Additional Info:**
I am using a Windows XP machine. I am connected to a virtual machine through Windows Remote Desktop Connection. The VM I am connected to is Windows 64-bit also XP machine.

Comment: Is the virtual machine on your physical machine? If so what software are you using to virtualise? For Virtualbox you can share folders easily for example. If not, perhaps you can just share a folder on your network as though it were a normal machine.

Comment: have you tried dragging and dropping?

Comment: drag and drop does not work I tried.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to copy/paste from your local machine to a remote machine using Windows' included Remote Desktop client. You just have to check a somewhat hidden checkbox in the Remote Desktop client.  Step-by-step instructions: http://superuser.com/a/454245/6091

Comment: @Saher did you try any of the solutions offered below?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the two machines are networked, why not just make a standard windows share from one machine accessible by the other?

Comment: I was just curious if a copy and paste feature can work somehow.

Comment: You can "copy and paste" onto the network share. Other than that... I think certain remote clients support clipboard sharing but its often an optional extra. I don't know about your client.

Comment: The Windows Remote Desktop client does, indeed, support copy/paste without having to explicitly configure Windows file sharing.  See my answer for step-by-step instructions; you just have to check a somewhat hidden checkbox. http://superuser.com/a/454245/6091

Answer (score 9):

1. Open Remote Desktop and click the Local Resources tab [image: Remote Desktop]
2. Check the Clipboard box and click More... [image: Local Resources tab]
3. Check Drives and click OK [image: More local resources dialog]

Now when you connect, you will be able to copy and paste files directly from the local machine to the remote machine.

Whereas the clipboard works for copying and pasting basic content such as text (assuming clipboard sharing is enabled), sharing disk drives via the Local Resources tab is the key to being able to seamlessly copy and paste files across Remote Desktop.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than give you a specific solution, judging by the way you have asked the question I think it may be more helpful for you to fundamentally see things in a way which you should.

Forget that it is a VM.  You can connect to it in all the same ways that you can with any other machine on your LAN, including from the host which runs the VM.

So just use network shares, or whatever other method you would usually use between two locally networked machines.

Answer (score 2):

Open the file system of remote machine using run. Steps are:

- click on Start -> run
- Type \IP addresss of remote machine
- type user id and password

Now you can see remote machine file system in explorer.
In the addres bar type: `\\ip_address\C$`
this will open the C drive of remote machine. Now you can paste the file here or traverse any other location and paste files. No need to share disk or folders.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution would be to save your files to a USB flash drive and then unplug and replug the device while you are in your VM's session. The VM should recognize it and you should be able to copy the files thus.

Answer (score 1):

Well if the VM you are connect to has an internet connection, you can use any number of online services to upload your files from the local machine and download them to the virtual machine. Some services you can use to upload files online are:

1. [Megaupload](http://www.megaupload.com/)
2. [Rapidshare](http://www.rapidshare.com/)
3. [Fileserve](http://www.fileserve.com/)

You can also zip your files and upload them to [GoogleDocs](https://docs.google.com/#home), even if they are not in a standard GoogleDocs format. Upto 1 GB of files are allowed by GoogleDocs.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy and past over a RDP connection.  But it is also possible to disable it. Make sure, on the local resources tab, that you check the *Clipboard*.

While you are connected to the VM, you'll see a processes called RDPclip.exe or something similar.  Kill it and restart it on the other side and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

For Microsoft systems it is possible to have copy paste option from host to virtual system. I have done with XP as host and 2003 enterprise edition as virtual machine. But i had used Microsoft Virtual PC for that...

Use **Edit** of Virtual PC software for simply drag the file from host to desktop of virtual system.

Answer (score 1):

IN VM,Just goto c drive>progfiles>Vm ware>vm tools
and press vmuser.exe file

Thats it..now you can copy data to VM and VM to local machine

Repeat this untill you get it..

Comment: VMWare wasn't really mentioned in the question, was it?

Answer (score 0):

Simply copy any file from local system, and paste it on the VM- virtual machine's desktop, You can then use it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple copy from local machine and paste on VM desktop worked like anything!
Local machine having windows 7 and Ubuntu VM in VMplayer.

Answer (score 0):

Open two CMD terminals one is for the local machine and the other is for the VM.

then create a folder in the VM using mkdir

then from your local machine terminal type the below command

`scp path_of_your_file username@ip_address_of_vm:folder_in_vm`

For Example:
`scp Desktop/John/index.html root@110.11.11.111:John`